# .NET MVC Routing Product Access

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, url, controller, routes

I have some routing problems. This is my defined route:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            "Order",
            "Order/{action}/{townName}/{restaurantName}",
            new { controller = "Order", action = "Browse", townName = UrlParameter.Optional, restaurantName = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This is my OrderController:

```
public class OrderController : Controller
{
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public OrderController()
        : this(new UnitOfWork())
    {
    }

    public OrderController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    // GET: /Order/

    public ViewResult Index(string searchString, string sortOrder, string currentFilter, bool showAllRestaurants = false)
    {
        var viewModel = new OrderIndex();
        //viewModel.Towns = _db.Towns
        //    .Include("Restaurants");
        viewModel.Towns = _unitOfWork.TownRepository.Get();

        ViewBag.ShowAllRestaurants = showAllRestaurants;

        if (showAllRestaurants)
        {
            ViewBag.SortNameParam = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";

            if (searchString == null)
                searchString = currentFilter;

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;


            viewModel.Restaurants = _unitOfWork.RestaurantRepository.Get();

            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name_desc":
                    viewModel.Restaurants = viewModel.Restaurants.OrderByDescending(r => r.Name);
                    break;
                default:
                    viewModel.Restaurants = viewModel.Restaurants.OrderBy(r => r.Name);
                    break;
            }

            // we will set showAllRestaurants = true but will filter them
            // by searchString if there is any searchString
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                viewModel.Restaurants = viewModel.Restaurants.Where(r => r.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
            }
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Order/Browse
    // first argument (string townName) is like (int id) parameter 
    // defined as custom route in /App_Start/RouteConfig.cs
    [BrowseFilter]
    public ViewResult Browse(string townName, string restaurantName, string sortOrder)
    {
        var viewModel = new OrderBrowse();

        // if we pass sortOrder argument - order ascending, else order descending
        ViewBag.NameSortParam = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";

        // retrieve selected town and its associated restaurants from database
        //viewModel.Restaurants = _db.Restaurants
        //    .Where(r => r.Town.Name == townName);
        viewModel.Restaurants = _unitOfWork.RestaurantRepository.Get(filter: r => r.Town.Name == townName);

        ViewBag.CurrentTown = townName;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(restaurantName))
        {
            //viewModel.Foods = _unitOfWork.FoodRepository.Get(filter: f => f.re
            viewModel.Foods = viewModel.Restaurants
                .Where(r => r.Name == restaurantName)
                .Single().Foods.OrderBy(f => f.Menu.Name);

            // initialize empty List so we can add Menus
            viewModel.Menus = new List<Menu>();
            foreach (Food food in viewModel.Foods)
            {
                if (!viewModel.Menus.Contains(food.Menu))
                {
                    viewModel.Menus.Add(food.Menu);
                }
            }

            ViewBag.CurrentRest = restaurantName;

            return View(viewModel);
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "name_desc":
                viewModel.Restaurants = viewModel.Restaurants.OrderByDescending(r => r.Name);
                break;
            default:
                viewModel.Restaurants = viewModel.Restaurants.OrderBy(r => r.Name);
                break;
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }}
```

This works pretty fine for end user when data is displayed, but now I started implementing admin stuff like CRUD methods on both Towns and Restaurants. Do I need to create new route, edit current one or what to have access to CRUD for just townname - something like `"Order/{action}/{townName}/{action}` and `"Order/{action}/{townName}/{restaurantName}/{action}"` for restaurant where (in both 2 just written routes) last {action} can be Edit, Delete or Create.

Do I need new Controller ?

Link to similar example would also be very useful.

Thanks.